# Unexpected 404 instead of 400 after migration to Spring Boot 3.2.1 from 2.7.17

Tags: java, spring-boot

In our project we used Spring Boot 2.7.17, OpenAPI specs and RestAssured for testing. Here's the part of API interface, generated from our spec:

```java
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/accounts/{accountId}/statements/{statementId}",
        produces = {"application/pdf", "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/tiff", "image/png", "application/json"}
)
ResponseEntity<Resource> getAccountStatement(
        @Parameter(name = "accountId", description = "Account Identifier", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("accountId") String accountId,
        @Parameter(name = "statementId", description = "Statement Identifier", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("statementId") String statementId
);
```

The implementation doesn't change anything:

```java
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getAccountStatement(String accountId, String statementId) {
    var consentId = customerClaimsProvider.getConsentId();
    var subject = getSubject();
    return accountListService.getAccountStatement(accountId, statementId, consentId, subject);
}
```

Here is our Groovy test (spock framework is used), pay attention to whitespaces in URI:

```
def "Run endpoint with undefined and empty data for getAccountStatement"() {
    setup:
    //...

    when:
    Response responseEmpty = baseSpec(accessToken)
            .get("accounts/v1/accounts/ /statements/ ")

    then:
    responseEmpty.then().statusCode(400)
}
```

Prior to migration the test was OK, but after upgrading SB to 3.2.1 the test began to fail as the controller now returns 404 instead of 400:

```
Condition failed with Exception:

responseEmpty.then().statusCode(400)
|             |      |
|             |      java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
|             |      Expected status code <400> but was <404>.
```

On the backend it corresponds this:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource accounts/%20/statements.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.17.jar:10.1.17]
```

Context path is described as

```yaml
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /open-banking/accounts/v1
```

Is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by proper encoding of parameters. In other words I've changed:

```
when:
Response responseEmpty = baseSpec(accessToken)
        .get("accounts/v1/accounts/ /statements/ ")
```

to

```
when:
Response responseEmpty = baseSpec(accessToken)
        .get("accounts/v1/accounts/{account}/statements/{statement}}", Map.of("account", " ", "statement", " "))
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems problem due to context path configuration. and in this case the problem is elsewhere, related to the Spring boot v2 to v3 migration I think. I would recommend you to remove context path and use another way. You can see it like another way to define and api initial endpoint:

in appication.properties:

```
app.apiPrefix=/open-banking/accounts/v1
```

And add this to your controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "${app.apiPrefix}")
```

This should solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks for participating, I put +1. The the issue was fixed on the test side.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue when I made an endpoint call with a trailing slash, even though it wasn't in the controller. However, this code helped me out, even though it is now considered deprecated.

```
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that answers that contain code only are generally considered as poor quality. Can you [edit] your answer and explain how it solves the problem that is described in the posted question?